# How to set placeholder text when using the WordPress TinyMCE wp_editor()

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, tinymce

Can you set placeholder text for the TinyMCE textarea generated by `wp_editor()`?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

My code is currently:

```
$settings = array( 'media_buttons' => false );
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

This generates a textarea with all the bells and whistles such as TinyMCE buttons and Quicktags but I can't see how I can set placeholder text. With a standard textarea you can do it like so:

```
<textarea name="content" placeholder="Write something"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

What follows won't give you an HTML5 `"placeholder"` attribute for your textarea but it will give you some text to display instead of an empty box:

I think usually you'd use wp_content by passing it all the bits and pieces it needs, like so:

```
wp_editor( stripslashes($content), $editor_id, $settings );
```

(The variable `$content` is a string which may have been obtained from the database or from a `$_POST` array, etc)

So i suggest that before you call the `wp_content()` function, test whether `$content` is empty  and if you find that indeed it is, then you could seed it with placeholder content:

```
if( strlen( stripslashes($content)) == 0) $content = "Write something";
wp_editor( stripslashes($content), $editor_id, $settings );
```