# wordpress WYSIWIG editor showing default helper text when I click save

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the below code to output a WYSIWIG editor on my custom post type:

```
$settings = [ 'media_buttons' => false,'quicktags' => false ];
$content = 'Optional Message For Your Friend here... ';                     
$editor_id = 'postcueeditor';
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id,$settings );
```

When user click save, the value is in fact saving, but the data inside the textarea still shows the helper text stored in `$content`. How would I go about changing this variable to show the value when something is stored in it? Is my above code too ancient for modern day WordPress installs? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable $content is a string which may have been obtained from the database or from a $_POST array, etc.

So i suggest that before you call the wp_content() function, test whether $content is empty and if you find that indeed it is, then you could seed it with placeholder content:

```
$settings = [ 'media_buttons' => false,'quicktags' => false ];
$editor_id = 'postcueeditor';
$content=get_the_content($post->ID); //for example
if( strlen( stripslashes($content)) == 0) $content = "Optional Message For Your Friend here...";
wp_editor( stripslashes($content), $editor_id, $settings );
```

Otherwise, If you will provide $content='Optional Message For Your Friend here... '; - directly it will store it in your database. You just need to show if it's value is empty.

Hope this will helps you.

For more information.

- [How to set placeholder text when using the WordPress TinyMCE wp_editor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341633/how-to-set-placeholder-text-when-using-the-wordpress-tinymce-wp-editor)
- [How to set placeholder text when using the WordPress TinyMCE wp_editor()](https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-set-placeholder-text-when-using-the-wordpress-tinymce-wp_editor.html)

Comment: thanks you rock. would you be able to update your response using a ternary solution for $content?